# How to get the result in Monitor result (Jmeter)?

Tags: asp.net, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

Am Using asp.net application, i have to view the result in Monitor results(Jmeter). Is there any possible ways to get result in Monitor result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Monitor Results listener documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Monitor_Results)

> Monitor Results is a new Visualizer for displaying server status. It is designed for Tomcat 5, but any servlet container can port the status servlet and use this monitor.

So there is no simple way to make it work with IIS.

You can use either built-in Windows monitoring tools to check IIS server and underlying OS health or consider using JMeter's [Server Performance Monitoring](http://Servers%20Performance%20Monitoring) plugin.

I also believe [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) will be extremely useful